# graphically (GUI) test Python scripts like jsfiddle

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm exploring 2D interpolations for the purpose of writing a script in Python. I've been using the PIL (Pillow) modules to quickly display the results of the algorithms - this is best for cases when interactive input isn't necessary (i.e. testing on a random set of points).

For interactive testing I've found jsfiddle to be the most lightweight solution, but I admit it isn't ideal to rewrite functions in another language merely to be able to move points around, and input specific shapes of quads.

[image: simple example of 4 points, drawn at random]
*simple example, 4 verts drawn at random (JavaScript in JS fiddle; would like to do the same in Python)*

What would be a fastest way to play around with a Python script graphically? Is there a Python counterpart of jsfiddle? I googled 'Python fiddle', of course, but it's not what I'm looking for. What I need is a simple canvas implementation and click events support.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Mayor difference that JS is always used in combination with HTML. While Python can be used with different GUI libraries, it does not have one by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is [Python Fiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/), but I think this question is going to be closed by admins as being off-topic on Stack Overflow; [see this thread here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719180/which-ide-for-scientific-computing-and-plotting-in-python)

I'd also come to think of [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) and [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda). The latter includes the former. These will harness matplotlib, amongst others, and Jupyter gives you a Matlab-like interpreter that shows you variable values for each line and you're able to step by step look at those variables and any graphs you are making.

Comment: That thread there could be the hint I'm looking for. I will try matplotlib.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't aware that matplotlib/pyplot had mouse and keyboard events but it does and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answer, there is Jupyter notebook – a software for interactive Python programming including graphical output.

You can run Jupyter locally or on your own server, but there are free cloud versions:

https://colab.research.google.com/

https://notebooks.azure.com/