# Scala IDE for data science applications (like RStudio / Spyder / Rodeo)

Tags: scala, ide, data-science

With the rise of Spark, Scala has gained a tremendous momentum as programming language of choice for data science applications.

To increase the efficiency when working on data science applications, **specialized IDEs** have been released for

- R (e.g. RStudio) and
- Python (e.g. Spyder or Rodeo, see [Is there something like RStudio for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305809/is-there-something-like-rstudio-for-python)).

Is there something similar for Scala?

Comment: The [Scala-IDE for Eclipse](http://scala-ide.org/) also has worksheets like IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any dedicated Data Science IDEs for Scala at this time. I think these would be your best options:

### [IntelliJ Worksheets:](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Worksheet)

[image: IntelliJ Worksheet]
This is basically a text editor with an output window which gets updated as often as you want. Eclipse has something similar, I just prefer IntelliJ.

**Pros:**

- Backed by IntelliJ's fantastic code completion, error checking, and sbt/maven integration.
- You can prototype within the same project setup as your actual development system (if you have one).

**Cons:**

- I am not aware of any caching/selective evaluation so the entire worksheet is evaluated each time you want an answer, something you may not want if you have some operations which take a long time to complete.
- No workspace variables window or plot integration.

### [Jupyter Notebooks](http://jupyter.org/)

[image: Jupyter Notebook]
The Jupyter Notebook is a generalization of the iPython notebook which now supports [dozens of interpreted languages](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages) (new kernels are being added all of the time).

**Pros:**

- [Scala](https://github.com/alexarchambault/jupyter-scala) and [Spark Scala](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree) Kernels are fairly easy to install, both have the ability to add maven/sbt dependencies and JARs.
- The cells in the notebook can be run individually (allowing you to train a model once and use it many times, for example).
- The cells support markdown (with LaTeX!) which can be rendered on its own ([a github example](https://github.com/EvanOman/KaggleCompetitions/blob/master/StackExchange/scala/Review_Aspect_Extraction_Spark.ipynb)), allowing you to use your notebooks as a report/demonstration.
- Notebooks are backed by a Notebook Server so you could easily use a more powerful computer as your notebook server and then interact with the notebook from another location.
- Some kernels have autocompletion.
- Looks like there is some plot integration ([example](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/chilang/b28319c2955d76219001/raw/645d4df74186548752a43f93eec3880e4e0d27d1/Bokeh.ipynb)) but it is not totally polished.

**Cons:**

- Not all kernels are perfect, some have bugs or limited functionality.
- No workspace variables window.
- You really need to be careful about the ordering of your cells, failure to do so can cause a lot of confusion.

---

For most of the data-sciency stuff I do I use Jupyter but it is far from perfect. In order for Scala to really take over as a Data Science language it really needs more data science libraries (scikit-learn is sooo far ahead here) and it needs a solid plotting library (there are a few options but none I have seen both use idiomatic Scala and are able to run without a server). I think as soon as it has those two elements it will become more popular and hopefully someone will make a nice RStudio-esque IDE.

Comment: I wonder if eclipse che will be the one after it gets scala support - http://www.eclipse.org/che/

Comment: Very interesting, hadn't heard of it before

Answer (score 4):

Your best shot (nothing like rstudio but this would be your best shot for scala) is [apache zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/)

[image: zeppelin]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look at Scala IDE for Eclipse. But i think, it really depends on your personal choice in which you are comfortable writing the code. For testing code by code, i would still use jupyter notebook