# data exploratory IDE (not including spyder) for python

Tags: python, ide, rstudio, jupyter-notebook, rodeo

I am a `python` user who is dependent on `pandas/numpy/bokeh` for data analysis.

I normally use `Jupyter notebook` for all my prototyping and exploratory work, however I find that the notebook does not provide a similar experience as `RStudio`. Although, I do not prefer coding in `R`.

I want to be able to do things like:

- explore dataframe objects and variables in a text editor
- have a workspace dedicated to plots so you can see your plots in that dedicated space rather than inline
- ipython console like functionality in the Terminal window workspace (`Rodeo's` Terminal is very weak and not conducive for extensive data analysis)

I found the following post on this topic: [is-there-something-like-rstudio-for-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305809/is-there-something-like-rstudio-for-python) .

The question in the above link was asked in **2011**. **6 years** have gone by and we don't have anything remotely legitimate as a solution.

So far, I have stumbled onto [Rodeo](https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo/) and [JupyterLabs](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterlab).

I have started to use `Rodeo`, however it is **extremely buggy** and **poorly designed**. In my opinion it is **not useable** for any data analysis task. As for `JupyterLabs` - it is in its infancy so not yet useable for anything.

**my QUESTIONS**:

1. Are there any other options than the two mentioned in this question?
2. Current status on `JupyterLabs` and timeline for official release? It seems `JupyterLabs` in theory solves all of the workflow problems I can think of that currently exist for users in `python` who are familiar with `Rstudio's` flow. I am already having problems launching Jupyter Labs (see: [jupyter lab - launches but don't see any tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753528/jupyter-lab-launches-but-dont-see-any-tabs)).

(`Rodeo` has good intentions but so far falls way short - I have already started filing bugs or design flaw tickets).

https://blog.jupyter.org/2016/07/14/jupyter-lab-alpha/

https://www.techatbloomberg.com/blog/inside-the-collaboration-that-built-the-open-source-jupyterlab-project/

Comment: and what is a problem? You didn' ask the question.

Comment: You could try asking on [Software Recs SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  However, you would need to make your question a good deal more specific than "RStudio-like".  You need to specify concretely what features you want and what you feel the existing programs lack.

Comment: why not spyder? I would say it's designed exactly for this. You can choose where your plots pop up, they can be in separate windows, interactive, rather than inline.

Comment: Too many reasons to mention here. I know Spyder has a strong following and I know it does a lot of things well but if it was that solid of an IDE for data science then we wouldn't have people allocating resources to develop others i.e. Rodeo, JupyterLabs etc.

Comment: Well, at least you should mention "too many reasons" that you don't like Spyder. Depending on that the answers, if any, should be different.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about JupyterLabs, but [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) is definitely a great solution to most of your problems. The community edition is free and has everything you required.

Comment: PyCharm, while a solid IDE, does not offer a workflow similar to Rstudio or that of Ipython/Jupyter. Its a great IDE for other purposes but not for data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enthought's Canopy. I am using it and it is very good Editor.
You can find it from [Get Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/)

I am using Free version of this. You can also use free version.

Hope this helps !