# Jupyter Lab - launches but don't see any tabs (look/feel is 100% different than seen in youtube videos)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have `jupyter notebook` version `4.2` on my `MacOS` (10.9.5)

I launch via `jupyter lab` at the MacOS terminal and it automatically opens a browser at the following link: `http://localhost:8888/lab`

At this point I see the `Welcome to the JupyterLab Alpha preview` screen but nothing more. No tabs etc. Please see the image I have included.

I am using `Chromium` (`Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)`
). When I try to open in `Safari` browser absolutely nothing loads. Its a blank browser session.

What I see in the browser doesn't look like anything that I have seen in all of the `JupyterLab` videos on youtube (`PyData 2016 DC` for example).

Clearly there is something wrong with the rendering.

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Output in the console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8888/terminals/websocket/1' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
http://localhost:8888/api/contents/untitled.txt?1485120059877 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:8888/api/contents/DeleteMe.ipynb?1485120060078 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Output in the MacOS terminal:

```
[I 16:20:58.569 LabApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from /Users/user1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 16:20:58.570 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/user1
[I 16:20:58.570 LabApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:20:58.570 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
[I 16:20:58.570 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 16:20:59.883 LabApp] No such file or directory: untitled.txt
[W 16:20:59.884 LabApp] 404 GET /api/contents/untitled.txt?1485120059877 (::1) 3.88ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
[I 16:20:59.893 LabApp] New terminal with specified name: 1
[W 16:21:00.095 LabApp] No such file or directory: DeleteMe.ipynb
[W 16:21:00.098 LabApp] 404 GET /api/contents/DeleteMe.ipynb?1485120060078 (::1) 5.14ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
[W 16:22:35.969 LabApp] 404 GET /lab/xterm.js.map (::1) 64.85ms referer=None
[W 16:25:30.075 LabApp] No such file or directory: untitled.txt
[W 16:25:30.076 LabApp] 404 GET /api/contents/untitled.txt?1485120330069 (::1) 1.74ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
[W 16:25:30.101 LabApp] 404 GET /lab/xterm.js.map (::1) 3.18ms referer=None
[W 16:25:30.296 LabApp] No such file or directory: DeleteMe.ipynb
[W 16:25:30.297 LabApp] 404 GET /api/contents/DeleteMe.ipynb?1485120330283 (::1) 1.73ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
```

Output of browser console:

[image]

UPDATE:

Here is a specific video of Jupyter Labs I watched:

[JupyterLab: Building Blocks...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ejh0ftSjk6g)

What I see is very different than what is shown in the video. There are many other videos on youtube.

UPDATE #2:

I followed Feynman27's instructions [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/408) however I get the same result. See screen shot. I see where it says, `Click on the Launcher tab for the initial JupyterLab screen`, however I can't find where that is.

[image]

UPDATE #3:

I updated my browser to `Chromium Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)`.

Now all works fine. I see the tabs.

Comment: Looks like (at least) the styles aren't (fully) loading. Do you see any errors in the console? View > Developer > Developer Tools

Comment: Please kindly see updates to question

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console? Open it by cmd+opt+i and go to 'Console'. Please add any errors if they appear.

Comment: Please see screenshot

Comment: @codingknob - Have you checked to see that something else isn't running on port 8888 that's preventing Jupyter lab from connecting? Stop Jupyter and run `netstat -nl | grep 8888` to see if something else is bound to that port.

Comment: nothing connected when I run `netstat -nl | grep 8888` after stopping Jupyter Lab.

Comment: Could you please start jupyter lab on another port : `jupyter lab --port 9999` and see if the issue is still present ?

Comment: @codingknob : from which path did you launch jupyter lab ?

Comment: @ThomasLehoux - starting from my home dir i.e. `/Users1/user1`

Comment: @ThomasLehoux - starting on `port 9999` results in the same problem.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running? Is there a default firewall or something that might be blocking connections?

Comment: 10.9.5 - Is there a default firewall enabled on OS X? I don't recall ever tinkering with such settings. But if there is a firewall, where are the settings? I can't seem to find anything

Comment: Perhaps this bug: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/408; note a comment provides a workaround.

Comment: Nope. Followed Feynman27's instructions and I get the same thing. I even deleted my python 2.7.x anaconda installation and installed the latest 3.x. I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: I updated my browser to `Chromium Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)`. Now all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated my browser to Chromium Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit). The prior version was `Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)`.

On the new version of `Chromium`, the `Jupyter Lab` works as expected.

I wanted to answer this question so any other users who experience something similar have a document resource to find a solution.

Answer (score 23):

I could not find an answer to this issue on Windows when searching Stackoverflow/Google/Bing, and this thread was quite prominent hence my Windows-specific answer here.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> did not work for me. On windows 10 with Jupyter 4.4.0, Jupyter Lab 0.35.4, the tabs in Jupyter Lab can be made visible/hidden by clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or toggling in the menu the options (*View > Single-document mode*).

[Jupiter Lab, menu item for toggling the Single-document mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0aC1.png)

Comment: Cmd + Shift + D on a Mac.

Answer (score 11):

Just pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> can toggle showing the tabs on/off. Often one tends to press by mistake and see it disappear

Answer (score 7):

Other shortcuts didn't worked for me in mac.

In Jupyter Lab 3.0 and later, there's a ***toggle botton at the bottom of the screen*** like below:
[image]

**Click on `Simple` toggle button** and you would be able to see all tabs.
Below trick works in the below jupyter version as follows:

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.3.0
qtconsole        : not installed
ipython          : 7.16.1
ipykernel        : 5.5.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.12
jupyter lab      : 3.0.0
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : not installed
nbformat         : 5.1.3
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Answer (score -3):

The Problem is You are not using any Notebook to open any notebook.
Type the following:

```
ipython notebook xyz.py
or
jupyter notebook xyz.py
```

Now you will be able to see the Notebook.

You can also browse in the left Screen to the directory where you have a Python script and then open that by clicking on the *.py file from that file explorer.

Comment: not sure I follow. If I run the above commands in my `OS X` terminal the result is: `[C 01:43:17.294 NotebookApp] No such file or directory: /Users/user1/xyz.py`

Comment: replace xyz.py with the Python file you want to open.

Comment: I'm not trying to open any specific python file. I just want to launch `jupyter lab` without the problems I am seeing.

Comment: Did you try opening any python file does the Jupyter lab open any existing *.py file? This will help determine if it is functional or not?

Comment: I tried what you suggest. It tried to open that file with the following URL: `http://localhost:8888/files/myscript.py` but the result plain text rendering.