# Sagemaker Studio tabs are not visible

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

In Sagemaker Studio my tabs are gone, how can I get them back?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bring back the tabs by selecting

```
View > Single-document mode
```

or by using the combination:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Windows)

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Mac)

got inspiration from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54476998/1771155